# Why is a heap better than a linked list for implementation of a priority queue?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, heaps, priority-queues

Using a heap, you have O(log(n)) insertion and O(log(n)) removal. Using a linked list, you have O(n) insertion and O(1) removal.

Why is it better to have log-n for both than n for one and constant time for the other?

Comment: Why would the opposite be true ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only really matters in the limit: for small sizes, the difference isn't really important.

But if you're doing a large number of each operation, $O(\log n) + O(\log n) = O(\log n)$ is asymptotically faster than $O(n) + O(1) = O(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have a simple equation: Number of insertions = number of removals + size of priority queue. If the number of insertions is n, then the heap will be faster as long as the number of removals is at least n / log n. And if the number of removals isn't that large, then your priority queue will grow in size very, very quickly.